# How to use a callback function on angucomplete-alt selected-object attribute?

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently working on the following code :

```html
<angucomplete-alt id="skill1"
                selected-object="addSkill1()"
                remote-url="@Url.Action("GetSkills", "ManageMission")/?query="
                title-field="Name"
                minlength="1"
                match-class="angucomplete-match"
                input-class="form-control"
                template-url="@Url.Content("~/Templates/angucomplete-alt.html")"></angucomplete-alt>
```

```js
$scope.addSkill1 = function () {
    console.log(arguments); 
};
```

By using a callback function, I'm trying to get the selected object value ([as explained in angucomplete-alt documentation](https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt)), but I receive the follwing error :

> Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'addSkill1()' used with
>   directive 'angucompleteAlt' is non-assignable!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I digged the example from: [Angucomplete Alt](http://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/#example3) and I find out that you must provide the `selected-object` like this, even if It's a **callback** function:

```
<angucomplete-alt id="skill1"
                selected-object="addSkill"
                remote-url="@Url.Action("GetSkills", "ManageMission")/?query="
                title-field="Name"
                minlength="1"
                match-class="angucomplete-match"
                input-class="form-control"
                template-url="@Url.Content("~/Templates/angucomplete-alt.html")"></angucomplete-alt>
```

And the **callback** method should receive the `selected` item as parameter:

```
$scope.addSkill = function (selected) {
    console.log(selected); 
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to receive more parameters on the addSkill function?

Comment: The Given the documentation, says that parameter is the selected item from the autocomplete. Maybe you can implement any other behavior using ng-change.

Answer (score 0):

For passing within the scope of ng-repeat, I created an initialiser function in the controller, which returns the callback function into that scope.

```
<html>
    <div ng-repeat="row in rows">
             ...
        <div ng-init="row.callbackFunction = initialiseCallback(row)"></div>
        <angucomplete-alt selected-object = "row.callbackFunction" />
             ...
    </div>
</html>
______________________
Controller() {
    $scope.initialiseCallback = function (row){
        return function (selected) {
            console.log(selected);  
            console.log(row); // should print the row number
        }
    }
}
```